# ansi: two fast questions about this term

Tags: sql, ansi

I'm a little confused about ANSI and sql.
Is the ansi/sql relationship the same as posix/unix?
Is sql language an ansi standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ANSI is the "American National Standards Institute". They are and organisation that defines standards for a very wide range of things: "from acoustical devices to construction equipment, from dairy and livestock production to energy distribution, and many more." [About ANSI](https://www.ansi.org/about_ansi/overview/overview?menuid=1)

SQL is a standard language for communicating with databases. This standard is defined by the American National Standards Institute in ISO/IEC 9075 and related documents.

One (of many) good source of practical information about SQL can be found at [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)